# How to create backpressure in an RxJava2 operator that emits varying number of items

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm trying to create a few backpressure honoring operations for a Flowable in RxJava2.

Specifically, I'm parsing an XML document: I have a Flowable streams of byte[], and transforming it into XMLEvents (tag start, tag end, piece of content, that kind of thing)

Without the backpressure, it is working fine, like in this RxJava1 operator:
https://github.com/flyaruu/xml-rx/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/codemonkey/xml_aalto_rxjava/XML.java

I'm porting this to RxJava2, and want to add backpressure capability, but I really struggle.

I'm looking at this section: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#request-accounting

There is an example of the RebatchRequests using a drain method, but I can't really figure out all the one-letter variables, the optimized code, what is generic 'drain' code and what is specific to RebatchRequests and even what concepts upstream and downstream even means in this context.

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious, as what I'm trying to do seems pretty generic: I consume an item, a byte[] in this case, and that results in zero-or-more XMLEvents. Based on that number of items I need to rebalance the requests. Is there an example out there that does this? Or some tutorial?

Comment: Sounds like you need `flatMap` or `flatMapIterable`.

Comment: That worked! I ended up using the 1-1 drain code in my operator from the documentation, and emitting Flowable<XMLEvent>, and finally flatmapping those. Thanks!